# Ajax like button not showing increment in count or else

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I wanted to add like heart button with like count. I want to use ajax for changing likes count and color change. but when I tried to do that it won't work.

HTML

```
<div id="posts">
        {% for post in page_obj %}
        <div><a >{{ post.userp }}</a></div>
        <div>{{ post.content }}</div>
        <div>{{ post.timestamp }}</div>
        <div id="post_name">
            {% if request.user in post.userl.all %}
            <a class="likeu" style="cursor: pointer"><span id="{{ post.id }}" class="likeu1" style="font-size:24px;color:red">&hearts;</span></a>
            {% else %}
            <a class="likeu" style="cursor: pointer"><span id="{{ post.id }}" class="likeu1" style="font-size:24px;color:grey">&hearts;</span></a>
            {% endif %}
            <p id="{{ post.id }}l">{{ post.userl.all.count }}</p>
        </div>
        <hr>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```

and JAVASCRIPT

```
    document.querySelectorAll('.likeu1').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', change_like));
function change_like(){
    post_id = this.id
    console.log(post_id)
    fetch('/likes', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
          post_id : post_id,
      })
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        value = result["is_liked"];
        console.log(value);
        console.log(this);
        if (value == 'true'){
            this.style.color = 'red';
            console.log('red');
        }
        else{
            this.style.color = 'grey';
            console.log('grey');
        }
    })
}
```

It is updating when I refresh but I want it without refresh.
I don't know what I am doing wrong. please help!

Comment: Is contain like count data in response?`<p id="{{ post.id }}l">{{ post.userl.all.count }}</p>` Is it like count display?

Comment: yes It is count display

Comment: You should carry like count data in resp and set that count in p.innerHtml